# Kafka topic lost all replicas after Leader election

Tags: apache-kafka

I am getting the below on trying to produce to(/consume from) a kafka topic :

```
[2019-12-12 17:33:53,049] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [wallet-V4_1_2-transactions-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

On further investigation, I could see that the In-sync replicas is now 0. 
Unfortunately, the partition and replication-factor was kept to 1 due to resource-constraints.

```
bin/kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 192.158.30.74:9092 --topic wallet-V4_1_2-transactions --describe
Topic:wallet-V4_1_2-transactions    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: wallet-V4_1_2-transactions   Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 2 Isr:
```

In the segment directory, I can see there is an additional file for `leader-epoch-checkpoint`

```
root@8436f52ec04c:/var/lib/kafka/data/wallet-V4_1_2-transactions-0# ls -lart
total 656
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup 10485756 Dec  4 06:50 00000000000000003235.timeindex
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup       10 Dec  4 06:50 00000000000000003235.snapshot
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup       18 Dec 10 04:49 leader-epoch-checkpoint
drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody nogroup     4096 Dec 10 04:49 .
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup   636034 Dec 10 11:55 00000000000000003235.log
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup 10485760 Dec 10 11:55 00000000000000003235.index
drwxrwxrwx 106 nobody nogroup    12288 Dec 15 06:22 ..
```

As mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-101+-+Alter+Replication+Protocol+to+use+Leader+Epoch+rather+than+High+Watermark+for+Truncation), the consumer/producer should not impacted by this. 
Other topics have recovered from the Leader failure and I am able to query them.

However, this topic still gives the error:

```
[2019-12-15 09:54:12,303] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-83858] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [wallet-V4_1_2-transactions-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

How can I recover the already published messages from kafka and preserve this topic

Comment: "brokers without a matching listener" .. What listeners **do** the brokers have? Looks like you're running Kafka in Docker?

Comment: Yes. I am running Kafka using the confluent docker image.

Comment: Okay. Can you please update the question with your container configurations? The only way to recover the topic is to recover the broker hosting that topic.

Comment: @cricket_007 The details for kafka are as below:  
/micro-service-volumes/kafka-cf-data /var/lib/kafka/data